# How do say "close to" re: location?

Tags: words

How would you say "A is close to B" ? As in, "A and B are nearby each other".

Would you use 近く here? If so, how?

Answer (score 9):

You can use either 「[近]{ちか}い」 or 「近く」, but each requires a different sentence structure.  That is because while the former is an adjective and the latter, a noun.

> 「A + **は** + B + **に** + 近**い**です。」
>
> 「A + **は** + B + **から** + 近**い**です。」
>
> 「A + **は** + B + **の** + 近**く** + **に** + あります。」

The particle choices are very important in these short phrases.

Comment: I haven't really seen that first option. Didn't know it was possible "に近い"

Answer (score 1):

AはBに近いです。

Lit. "To B, A is close" but more likely to be translated "A is close to B".

Comment: Any reason for using が?  You need a specific reason to use が as a subject-marker.  Also, you cannot say ～～に近くです.

Comment: Yeah my grammar was all wrong/typo'd, it's late...