# この近くにレストランはありますか - Why Chikaku and why koko(DE)?

Tags: learning

I've been trying to study japanese in small increments (an hour a day) for around 2-3 weeks now. I have a 2 questions regarding this sentence. From what I learned so far, DE is used instead of NI when referring to a location where a specific action will happen like ここで本を読みます vs そこに行きます.

Could you please explain why 'Koko DE' was used and not 'koko NI' here because by my understanding, there's no action involved in this statement. Also, I would like to know why Chikaku was used here rather than chikai. Isn't Chikai an adjective which describes the noun, like in this sentence, it describes the restaurant. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/how-do-say-close-to-re-location/22880#22880

Comment: I don't see a ここで in the sentence you posted...?