# Usage of の v/s から

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 私の家は[駅]{えき}**の**[近]{ちか}くです.
>
> 私の家は[駅]{えき}**から**[近]{ちか}くです.

Is there any functional difference between the two sentences? Or do they mean the same? I am somewhat of a beginner and the difference doesn't seem apparent to me since both can mean

'My house is near the station.'

Do let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22876/9831

Comment: The linked post is related, but not a duplicate. Going over it, one can be lead to believe that 近く cannot take a modifying phrase headed by から and thus Xから近く is a ungrammatical construction. But that by no means is the case. It is very much grammatical and very much in use, whether as the complement of a locative に (「駅から近くにある」) or as a predicative noun phrase (「駅から近くです」).

Comment: @goldbrick Ah! So, in that case, there is no difference between 「駅から近くです」v. 「駅から近いです」? Thank you for your input!

Comment: Meaning-wise, they are effectively the same.